# Why are subjects upside down when I look through my door peephole?

Tags: optics, visible-light, observers

There is a convex lens 3/4" on the outside and 1 1/2" convex lens on the inside.
Each lens has one flat side facing out and one convex side facing in.

What can be done to correct this image?

Comment: If you already know the basics of ray optics you may find that the [lens maker's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_(optics)#Lensmaker.27s_equation) is a big help in estimating the expected behavior of simple systems for which you have only eyeball measurements.

Comment: This operation is called "image erection" and is usually accomplished with a prism. Google "Porro prism" or "roof prism"